# Unit Test fails with GrailsConfigurationException - cannot find responsible line of code

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock, grails-3.0

I am writing unit tests for my Grails 3.0.3 application with standard spock framework. Everything as scaffolded by

```
grails create-app
```

I created my unit test with

```
grails create-unit-test
```

Added manually @TestFor annotation and test logics. I get

```
mypackage.MyClassSpec > test myMethod method FAILED
org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException
```

[GIST of My test class (generalized and simplified)](https://gist.github.com/PiotrZakrzewski/459e380e560d3dca5ce0)

There is no line number in stacktrace after running

```
grails test-app --stacktrace
```

How can I find out what is causing this exception?

Comment: What does the toTsv(listOfMaps) method need to do its work? Configuration settings? Other services? Those all need to be mocked in the unit test case. Without seeing the toTsv code, it's hard to have any concrete ideas for help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your remarks. This is a self contained method which does not rely on any external service, it just takes in a list of maps. 
I have solved this issue however - I deleted @TestFor Annotation... and now it works. I would still want to understand why it fails, I am still learning Grails and Spock so it might be some elementary mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TestFor](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html) annotation is used to test Grails artefacts (yes, that's how it's spelled in the source code).

> The TestFor annotation defines the class under test and will
>   automatically create a field for the type of class under test. For
>   example in the above case a "controller" field will be present,
>   however if TestFor was defined for a service a "service" field would
>   be created and so on.

The class you were testing is a plain Groovy class, not a Grails controller, service, etc. So, BAM! You got an awkward exception.